# Is there a way in TypeScript to have an interface with optional fields that can only be set together?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

How can I write a TypeScript interface along the lines of the following:

```
type FavoriteColorDescription =
    | {
          color: "Red" | "Blue";
          reasonForBeingFavoriteColor: string;
      }
    | object;

type FavoriteShapeDescription =
    | {
          shape: "Square" | "Circle";
          reasonForBeingFavoriteShape: string;
      }
    | object;

interface Person extends FavoriteColorDescription, FavoriteShapeDescription {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

// Valid
const john1: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
};

// Valid
const john2: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    color: "Red",
    reasonForBeingFavoriteColor: "I like red",
};

// Invalid - 'reasonForBeingFavoriteColor' is missing, if 'color' is set,
// so should 'reasonForBeingFavoriteColor';
const john3: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    color: "Red",
};

// Valid
const john4: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    color: "Red",
    reasonForBeingFavoriteColor: "I like red",
    shape: "Square",
    reasonForBeingFavoriteShape: "I like squares",
};

// Invalid - 'reasonForBeingFavoriteShape' is missing, if 'shape' is set,
// so should 'reasonForBeingFavoriteShape',
const john5: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    color: "Red",
    reasonForBeingFavoriteColor: "I like red",
    reasonForBeingFavoriteShape: "I like squares",
};
```

I have tried the above, and searched on this issue, but have not found an answer. I wonder if there is no way to do that in typescript?
I know that i can define these object as an inner value like:

```
type FavoriteColorDescription =
    | {
          color: "Red" | "Blue";
          reasonForBeingFavoriteColor: string;
      }
    | object;

type FavoriteShapeDescription =
    | {
          shape: "Square" | "Circle";
          reasonForBeingFavoriteShape: string;
      }
    | object;

interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    favoriteColorDescription?: FavoriteColorDescription
    favoriteShapeDescription?: FavoriteShapeDescription
}
```

But this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: ① Your code has quite a few typos (so many semicolons in invalid places); please [edit] it so that it's a [mre] and others don't have to fix problems unrelated to your question in order to help. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7Ql4W) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate duplicate target).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, ① I originally wrote the code on the fly, but have now edited and fixed it as requested. ② The approach you've provided solves my question exactly! Thanks very much, you may post an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. ③ I would very grateful if you can also add a reference or a source to learn from about this to your answer. Thanks again kindly 

Comment: Please see the linked q/a for more information. Using the `AllOrNone` utility from there for the code here gives [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WJrY5W), which is equivalent to my earlier suggestion.